# Check differentiability of multivariable functions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> I am trying to determine if the following functions are (totally)
>   differentiable at $(x,y)=(0,0)$.
>
> $$f(x,y)=\sqrt{\vert xy \vert}$$
>
> $$g(x,y)=e^{{{\vert x \vert}^3}y}$$

However I am not particularly sure where to start. The concept of the total derivative being the Jacobian matrix makes sense but I don't really understand how to work with functions that may not have a Jacobian matrix. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If there's no Jacobian matrix, then the function certainly cannot be differentiable. Remember that sometimes you have to use the *definition* of the partial derivatives, rather than formulas. Why do both partial derivatives of $f$ at the origin equal $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $(0, 0)$. Then the derivative would be $0$ since

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lvert f(h, 0) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert} = 0 = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\lvert f(0, h) \rvert}{\lvert h \rvert}.$$

On the other hand,

$$\lim_{(h,h)\to 0}\frac{|f(h,h)-f(0,0)-0|}{|(h,h)|}=\frac 1 {\sqrt{2}},$$

which reveals that

$$\lim_{(h,k)\to 0}\frac{|f(h,k)-f(0,0)-0|}{|(h,k)|} \neq 0$$

and therefore, $f$ is not differentiable at $(0, 0)$.

I leave the calculation for $g$ to you. (Hint: Consider $x > 0$ and $x < 0$.)